# Unable to verify form has been filled out with CasperJS & jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs, casperjs, headless-browser

I have got a form that I am trying to fill using CasperJS. The code itself doesn't appear to have any problems (no errors being returned) - but I seem unable to 'check' that the form has been filled out.

When I dump the 'first_name' it appears to be blank - even though I have set this to be filled with the string 'Joe' - any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
casper.start(url);
casper.then(function() {
    this.fill('form[name="phones_display"]', {
        'first_name'            : 'Joe', // Required
        'last_name'             : 'bloggs', // Required
        'check_payable'         : '', // name to cheque if different from your name
        'payment_method'        : 'check', // Required check, paypal
        'shipping_method'       : '', // envelope, fedex
        'email_address'         : 'joe@bloggs.com', // Required
        'paypal_email_address'  : '',
        'telephone_number'      : '12345678', // Required
        'street_address_1'      : '', // Required
        'street_address_2'      : '',
        'city'                  : '', // Required
        'state'                 : '',
        'zip_code'              : '', // Required
        'hear'                  : '',
        'otherreason'           : ''
    }, true);
});

casper.then(function() {
    var first_name = this.evaluate(function() {
        return $('input[name="first_name"]').val();
    });

    require('utils').dump(first_name);
});
casper.run();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because after fill the form, it is submitted. so when you try to get the input 'the first name', the form has been cleaned.  In order to avoid this, just change the third parameter of casper.fill() method to false.

```
fill(String selector, Object values[, Boolean submit])
```

Example:

```js
this.fill('form[name="phones_display"]', {
    'first_name'            : 'Joe', // Required
    'last_name'             : 'bloggs', // Required
     .... 
}, false);
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for some reason - this is the full js code in a jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/SD3VR/

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out... the page has messed up form tags so my code was never going to work :-(